# get_declared_classes in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have app in Symfony 3.4 and I need to get all classes registered in my AppBundle namespace.
I use `get_declared_classes()`. I've created custom namespace `AppBundle\MyCustom` and I keep there some classes. The problem is that symfony caches `get_declared_classes()` and it does not cache my custom namespace. When I use `get_declared_classes()` for the first time (after remove of cache files) I get all my custom classes, but I am getting a problem when I run script for next time. Any ideas?

here is repo with a problem:
https://github.com/webostin/getdeclaredclasses

Comment: Which environment do you use? Cache shouldn't be a problem in `dev` environment

Comment: does not matter it happens in prod and dev same time

Answer (score 1):

> `The problem is that symfony caches get_declared_classes()`

This is a PHP function, Symfony has no control over it.

The problem is might related to autoloading. On the 1st load, Symfony has to build the cache, so includes your class. With a warm cache this is not necessary, so your class is not autoloaded. `get_declared_classes` wont include your classes.

You can observe this behavior by putting `$class = new MyTool();` in the 1st line of your execute method. This will trigger the autoloader, and your class will show up in declared classes.

Solution: It seems you want to get all classes implementing an interface. You can use DI for this.

Create a custom tag, and a manager class, and then use the manager class to access all tagged services in you command.

More here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#creating-custom-tags

Comment: DI is that what I do not want to use, this is why I use `get_declared_classes()`. Of course `get_declared_classes()` is PHP function :) and when I wrote `symfony caches` I just wrote in sorter way the same sentance as yours: 
>  On the 1st load, Symfony has to build the cache, so includes your class